# Nuxt js external URL and auto close

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I was in the process of creating a PWA using NUXT. I'm using Veutify as the design component.
My requirement is:

- I need to open a external URL, inside the app itself (not in a new browser page/tab)
- Secondly, I need to detect closing or url change on the page loaded, and trigger a router push automatically

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For your first question, if you want to access an external url in Vuetify, use the 'href' attribute instead of the 'to' attribute. e.g

```
    <v-btn
      large
      nuxt
      depressed
      rounded
      href="https://www.google.com/"
      >Access Google</v-btn
    >
```

And for your 2nd question, you can use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) e.g

```
watch:{
$route (to, from){
    //Perform action here
   }
}
```